# Asynchrounous call issue in Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am working with Angular5 , I have a big issue (please see the below code)
**In simple words it is a asynchronous execution issue, how to reduce this**

```
 let confirmData = {
            dlgHeader: 'Add',
            msgTxt: 'Are you sure to Add Language!!',
            eventName: 'locationmanagement_languages_assign'
        };
        this.confirmService.confirmData = confirmData;
   (1)   this.confirmationService.setShowConfirm(true);
   (2)    this.confirmAnchor.createConfirmation(ConfirmationComponent);
this.confirmService.getReturnValue()
        .subscribe(
        suc => {
            if (suc.eventName == 'locationmanagement_languages_assign') {
            this.assignLanguage(suc);
            }
        });
```

in above (1) line of code is responsible to create confirmation.(i have created custom confirmation component)
inside custom confirmation user can click CONFIRM/CANCEL buttons.
I want to stop (2) line code execution until user click CONFIRM/CANCEL buttons in custom confirmation component.
  Now i am using as below in language.component.ts  ,, but i am calling the getReturnValue() in ngOnInit().
  I dont want to use ngOnInit() to get action from custom confirmation component either it is CONFIRM/CANCEL action

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.getReturnValueEvent();
    }


 assignLanguageEvent() {
        debugger;
        this.requestedData = [];
        for (let data of this.selectedAssignLanguages) {
            this.requestedData.push({
                id: data.value.id,
                set_value: data.value.setValue
            });
        }
        console.log('Requested Data::', this.requestedData);
        let confirmData = {
            dlgHeader: 'Add',
            msgTxt: 'Are you sure to Add Language!!',
            eventName: 'locationmanagement_languages_assign'    
        };
        this.confirmService.confirmData = confirmData;
        this.confirmationService.setShowConfirm(true);
        this.confirmAnchor.createConfirmation(ConfirmationComponent);
    }

    getReturnValueEvent() {
       this.subscription1 = this.confirmService.getReturnValue()
        .subscribe(
        suc => {
            if (suc.eventName == 'locationmanagement_languages_assign') {
            this.assignLanguage(suc);
            }
        }
        );
    }
```

Comment: is there any one to help me

Comment: Can you please provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: sorry @bugs, what is stackblitz example, is it like plunkr

Comment: Yes, it can be a plunkr, a stackblitz... whatever, as long as we can reproduce the issue

Comment: ok will provide and let you know